# condition issue with Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

variables:
branches: $[ or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/branch/ayush'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/'))]

[image]

This ${{ if eq(variables.branches, 'true') }} condition is not being executed and so the value of var is not being set. However if i set branches to true, it works.

[image]

I do not understand what the issue is. What data type does branches have?boolean or string.

Comment: Hi @Ayush,
Have you tried the following steps?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, this problem is related to the [expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax).

When you are using the runtime expression "$[]", it works in runtime of the pipeline and "${{}}" is compile time syntax, it works before the runtime. So, the condition "${{if...}}" cannot get the value of the "branches" variable.

As a workaround, you can try to use [specific condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) to [set the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#about-tasksetvariable).

```
variables:
  branches: $[ or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/branch/ayush'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/'))]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.branches, 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage B!
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var;]value"
```